# Question regarding C loops

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm not exactly sure why this isn't returning what it should be, perhaps one of you could help me out. I have the following for loop in C:

```
for (i=0; i<nrow; i++) {
    dat[k]=l.0;
    k++;
}
```

Now, you would think that this would set all values of `dat` (of which there are `nrow` values) to 1.0; Instead, it is being set to 0. The program compiles fine and everything goes smoothly. The memory is properly allocated and `dat` is defined as a `double`.

Is there a reason this is yielding 0? I'm guessing the 0 is coming from the initialization of the `dat` variable (since I used `calloc` for memory allocation, which supposedly initializes variables to 0 (but not always)).

EDIT: Please note that there is a specific reason (this is important) that I'm not defining it as `dat[i]`. Additionally. `k` was defined as an integer and was initialized to 0.

EDIT 2: Below is the entire code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#define NCH 81

// Generate swap-mode data for bonds for input.conf file

int main() 
{
    int i,j,k;
    int **dat2;
    double *dat;

    int ns = 500;

    int nrow = NCH*(ns-1);

    dat = (double*) calloc(nrow, sizeof(double));
    dat2 = (int**) calloc(nrow,sizeof(int*));

    /*for (i=0; i<nrow; i++) {
        dat2[i] = (int*) calloc(2, sizeof(int));
        for (j=0; j<2; j++)
            dat2[i][j] = 0;
    }*/

    k=0;

    printf("\nBreakpoint\n");

    /*for (i=0; i<81; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<250; j++) {
            dat[k] = j+1;
            k++;
        }

        for (j=251; j>1; j++) {
            dat[k] = j-1;
            k++;
        }
    }*/

    FILE *inp;
    inp = fopen("input.out", "w");

    for (i=0; i<nrow; i++) {
        dat[k]=1.0;
        k++;
    }

    //fprintf(inp, "%lf\n", dat[i]);

    printf("%d", dat[nrow]);
    printf("\nDone\n");
    fclose(inp);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!
Amit

Comment: Any reason you have an l there instead of a 1 in 1.0? Also, the rest of the code would be useful (where you initialise the pointers and variables) since this has an effect on the result. Additionally, you may not be iterating or accessing values in the array properly when you come to print them out.

Comment: Is dat[k] = 'ell'.0; instead of `one.0` a typo when transcribing here or in your source?

Comment: The rest of the code has been provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("%d", dat[nrow]);
```

is not valid, because the nrow'th element of dat doesn't exist.

Comment: Yup. returning `dat[nrow-1]` does in fact return 1.0. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are starting 'k' at zero?

In the sample you posted you are using l not 1 - is this just a typo?

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. I just fixed it and it's stil returning 0.0000

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<nrow; i++) {
    dat[k]=1.0;
    k++;
}
```

That should work.

Comment: I have 1.0, it was a typo on my case, I'll fix it in description

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

I'm assuming the l.0 is a type and your l is actually a 1.

Secondly, why are you using k in your for loop instead of using i?  Try using this instead:

```
for (i=0; i<nrow; i++) {
    dat[i]=1.0;
}
```

Comment: I specifically do not want to do that. There are reasons behind that, for which I would not get into right now. But if you look at the commented stuff, perhaps you'll understand.

Answer (score 0):

Either this works your compiler/hardware is bugged.

```
k = 0;

for (i=0; i < nrow; i++) {
    dat[k++] = 1.0f;
}

printf("%d, %d", dat[0], dat[nrow - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you `printf("%d", dat[nrow])`, `dat[nrow]` has not been set to 1. In the for loop the condition is `i < nrow` so it's before it. You need `i <= nrow`.